# 3D interactive graph with labels for individual points

Tags: browser, graph, 3d, visualization, vis.js

I'm trying to graph data similarly to [this](http://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/examples/netflix_tsne.jpg), except using an actual 3rd dimension instead of color. Vis.js would have been exactly what I want, except it doesn't seem to support labels for individual points. Where can I get interactive, preferably in-browser, 3D graph visualization for this type of data?

Answer (score 0):

The Graph3d of vis.js doesn't support setting labels for individual data points, but you can set tooltips, see:  http://visjs.org/examples/graph3d/11_tooltips.html. Maybe that's a workable solution for you? If not, you could open a feature request for this: https://github.com/almende/vis/issues